# MongoDB - тормоз вставки после 5000000 записей

Tags: java, база-данных, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

Всем привет. В общем проблема такая: Проект на JAVA и есть NoSQL DB - MongoDB, необходимо работать примерно с 1000000000 записей. Вставка, в пустую таблицу, 5000000 записей, происходит за 13-15 мин, но после вставки 5000000 дальнейший процесс вставки начинает тормозить и чуть ли не в геометрической прогрессии и ОЗУ начинает пожирать немерено. Приоритетной задачей этой БД является поиск (скорость поиска на 10000000 - удовлетворяющая)

**Вопрос:**

1. Почему так происходит?
2. Как это исправить?

**Возможные варианты решения:**

3. Каждые 5000000 записей - создавать новую таблицу?
4. Оптимизация индексов? (у меня поиск по id)
5. Оптимизация конфига MongoDB?
6. Оптимизация системы?
7. Замена БД?

Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, все индексы mongodb держит в оперативной памяти. Если id - uuid, он занимает 16 байт на запись, плюс какие-то накладные расходы на струкруру. В общем, подозреваю, что это всё дело перестаёт влазить в память и либо mongodb вообще выкидывает этот индекс, либо начинает работать системный своп, который весьма медленный и аффектает ещё и другие приложения.

Answer (score 1):

У меня был похожий случай когда я работал с **SQLite**. Приходилось перейти на **MySQL**.

Но для миллиарда записей по моему вам надо будет перейти уже на **BigTable**. Например, на **Hadoop**, **HBase** или **Cassandra**.

Насчет **Cassandra** если честно не уверен, потому что Facebook сам перешел от **Cassandra** на **HBase** хотя сами разработали ее.

[bigtable](/questions/tagged/bigtable)[база-данных](/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: Спасибо. Вероятно Вы правы, что придется менять у меня в данный момент уже есть бока и кассандрой к примеру:
Таким образом наверное придется еще HBase покрутить ну и Hadoop вероятно тоже. Просто в моем распоряжении только одна нода и маловероятно что заказчик раскошелится еще на несколько.   
Кстати говоря Вы что либо знаете о Aerospike ? 
на всякий случай мои координаты avkcorporation@gmail.com
Спасибо.
 продолжение в след. коменте

Comment: _MongoDB-3.4 WiredTiger
Cassandra - datastax-3.9.0
На счет инсертов: 
Монга
 - сингл инсерты 1млн=2мин 12с, до 5 млн скорость примерно такая же, после начинает круто уменьшаться
5млн=12-15мин 
- "батчинг" 1млн = 33сек, с каждым последующим скорость также уменьшается. в общем сегодня был результат 1млн= 2 мин
на 5млн подождал 10 мин и вырубил
конфиг по умолчанию_

Comment: Касандра
- сингл инсерты 1млн=27мин скорость вставки постоянная тестил всю ночь ))
- батчинг - 1млн=48с. но после 2го-3го млн. Вылетает WriteTimeoutException и пока что толком не разобрался что происходит дальше.
В принципе немного поковыряв конфиг касандры, раздуплил батчинг до 4-5млн но потом снова получаю WriteTimeoutException
Также проводя исследования с помощью JProfiler выяснил что скорость вставки действительно падает после каждого миллиона и нагрузка на проц увеличивается, GC начинает НЕ отрабатывать.

Comment: Увы я не изучил другие БД кроме SQL подобных углубленно.

Comment: Хотя запуск GC в ручном режиме, тоже - не помогает

Comment: А я вот лишился девственности по NoSQL ;)

Comment: Если вы сразу 1 млн записей проводите одним запуском возмозно БД будет зависать. Попробуйте вместо 1 млн за один раз - 100 по 10000.

Comment: Честно говоря я так  делаю - по 1000